# Need proper guideline for SCJP

Tags: java, scjp

I want to do SCJP certification and dont want to join coaching for that,so need suggestion on 
Without joining coaching how to prepare for SCJP???

Comment: Thought of sharing my experience http://www.developandconquer.com/2011/12/cleared-ocpjp-6-d.html

Answer (score 2):

I did the exam with the only help of the "[official book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060)" and the tests it includes. Passed with 90-something%, after reading the book and doing all its exercises a couple of times.

You may also want to check the forums at [JavaRanch](http://www.javaranch.com/).

If you have experience with Java, the exam will be relatively easy. If not, I would suggest you to code quite a lot for at least 6 months basic Java programs (console only is ok, no need to go into fancy web sites) to get a good grasp of the language and increase your chances to pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry about wasting your times with coaching classes, here i tell you a self study guide i used for my exam, i used **[scjp 6](http://www.epractizelabs.com/certification/sun/scjp-exam-6.html)** certification training lab for my preparation. I got 58 questions as right out of 60 questions with this tool. It may be help for every one.